# Line break problems in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, line-breaks

My problem is that I need only ONE break line and when I run the program, it "magically" create one additional (I not know of where is in the code)

I have the following:

```
NotifyIcon1.Text = "Arduino Sensor Monitor" & vbCrLf & dato & "ºC"
```

when dato is a variable.

And it's resulting in:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/kuxE5Mb.png]

I know that `vbCrLf` is to do the break line, but I not know why create multiple line breaks when I put it one ONE TIME.

Comment: There is probably a line break in `dato`

Comment: I need only the line break before of dato, not after. I edited the post  to see better what happens.

Comment: As Scott mentioned, it could be that your `dato` itself contains a line break. Try printing out `dato` alone, do you get a line break after its text?

Comment: No break lines in dato.

Comment: "No break lines in dato" is impossible with the code you're showing. How is `dato` assigned?

Comment: Ok, sorry, I'm bad, dato for some reason has a break line.

Comment: dato = dato.Replace("C", "")

Comment: dato is a number with a letter extracted of the prints of arduino. Is temperature in ºC. I use as output "temperature"C. Example: 18C and I use the C letter to identify that these value is temperature and not another thing. On my visual basic I not need to print the C letter.

Answer (score 1):

As it is, your code

```
NotifyIcon1.Text = "Arduino Sensor Monitor" & vbCrLf & dato & "ºC"
```

does the following:

Taking the string "Arduino Sensor Monitor", adding a new line to it, then the content of the `dato` variable, and finally concatenating "ºC" to that, without any added line break.

So, as `&` should not add a line break, my guess is that your `dato` variable does include a line break. If so, using `Replace` should do the trick:

```
dato = Replace(dato, vbCrLf, "") 'removing line breaks in dato
NotifyIcon1.Text = "Arduino Sensor Monitor" & vbCrLf & dato & "ºC"
```

Comment: Is a very good idea remove the line breaks in dato using Replace, but still keeps the line break.